# sharepoint-2013 hover not working on other elements

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

The tag `hover:` is not working on my Sharepoint 2013 Page
  or works only when it's referring to the own element
not when it refers to others

---

Example:

this-works:

```
highlight:hover {color: #ff0000;} `
```

this do not work:

```
highlight:hover .someclass{color: #ff0000;}
```

When I try to insert the second example it even delete my code line.

Comment: what do  you tried code ? plz insert your question

Comment: what is your html structure ?

Answer (score 0):

**Your code completely  worked.**

**Notes:** i just change a `color: green` into `highlight:hover .someclass` because you can easy to understand your code completely  work.

```css
highlight:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
highlight:hover .someclass {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<highlight>
  <h1>
   Hello
   </h1>
  <span class="someclass"> SomeClass </span>
</highlight>
```

Comment: problem is, both of them work on a normal page, but the second one one does not work in Sharepoint-2013 because it deletes the line